# Generic Lift Class

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers

I've just hacked up the following class as follows:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

import Control.Monad.Trans.Class (MonadTrans, lift)

class GenericLift m1 m2 where
  genericLift :: m1 a -> m2 a

instance GenericLift m m where
  genericLift = id

instance (MonadTrans t, Monad m2, GenericLift m1 m2) => GenericLift m1 (t m2) where
  genericLift = lift . genericLift
```

This allows lifting an arbitrary number of levels, which can be useful for generic functions that apply to different transformer stack sizes. Two questions:

1. Am I reinventing the wheel? Does this already exist and if so where?
2. Is this a sensible thing to do or silly?

Comment: There are a few libraries which do this. You may find [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8t8fjkISjus) interesting, in particular starting at 13:01.

Comment: The library which is most similar to your implementation is the [MonadStack](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/MonadStack-0.1.0.3/docs/Control-Monad-MonadStack.html) library.

Comment: This isn't all that useful an abstraction. There is no relation between two type parameters, one of which occurs in a negative position and the other in a positive position, so the situations in which the compiler can infer the correct types to use are very limited. You can solve this problem in a much simpler way, by replacing concrete monads with constraints (e.g. `StateT S (Reader R) a` becomes `(MonadState S m, MonadReader R m) => .. m a ..`) which allows you to embed such a stack in any larger stack without any lifting at all.

Comment: Here's another implementation on Hackage: [elevator](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/elevator-0.2.3/docs/Control-Elevator.html).

Comment: more links: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/layers-0.1/docs/Documentation-Layers-Overview.html is an (older, circa-2013) survey of many different attempts at solving the "lift" problem